# Mutation Input Split Across Two Apollo GraphQL Federated Services

Tags: graphql, apollo-federation

I have a mutation in my Graph that uses two datasources. We are migrating one of the datasources out to a federated service. That datasource in the federated service uses a portion of the input from the mutation being called. The originating service also uses a portion of the input. For example:

```
mutation($verifyUserInput: VerifyUserInput!) {
  verifyUser(input: $verifyUserInput) {
    user {
      specialId
    }
    otherServiceField
  }
}
```

I need to pass part of the `VerifyUserInput` to the other service that is not the PK for the entity. I can't find the input in the `__resolveReference` function `reference` (obviously since reference only passes the typename and PK), `context`, or `info` args. Is the original input to the mutation available in the federated service? If so how can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sniffing for the exact input I needed on every request in the gateway and adding that value to a header so it could propagate across the services. This definitely feels like a hack. I assume there is a more correct way to do this in Apollo Federation.